# Не могу подключиться к камере

Tags: java, android, камера

Я создаю приложение с возможностью сделать фотографию при помощи кнопки. Когда я нажимаю кнопку выскакивает сообщение "Can't connect to Camera" подскажите, как исправить код, так что бы сообщение заработало?

```
package com.example.nn.gallery;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import java.util.Date;

import java.io.File;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class CallCamera extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button takePictureButton;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private Uri file;

    //private static String imgPath = "/src/main";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_call_camera);

        takePictureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.photoBtn);

        imageView         = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        takePictureButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                takePicture(v);
            }
        });

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            takePictureButton.setEnabled(false);
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] { Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE }, 0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == 0) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                takePictureButton.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }
    }

    public void takePicture(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        file = Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile());

        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, file);

        startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
    }

    private  File getOutputMediaFile(){
        //imgPath
        /**
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "CameraDemo");
        **/

        File mediaStorageDir = new File(getApplicationFilePath(this.getApplicationContext()));

        //File mediaStorageDir = new File(imgPath);
        System.out.println(mediaStorageDir.getAbsolutePath());

        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()){
            Log.d("CameraDemo", "directory don't exists");

            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                Log.d("CameraDemo", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        return new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 100) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                imageView.setImageURI(file);
            }
        }
    }

    public static String getApplicationFilePath(Context context) {
        final File filesDir = context.getFilesDir();
        if (filesDir != null) {
            return filesDir.getAbsolutePath();
        }

        //  Log.w(ACRA.LOG_TAG, "Couldn't retrieve ApplicationFilePath for : " + context.getPackageName());
        return "Couldn't retrieve ApplicationFilePath";
    }
}


<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.nn.gallery.CallCamera">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/photoBtn"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/photoBtn"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Photo"
        android:id="@+id/photoBtn"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: can't connect to the camera]

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, так как на русском SO вопросы должны быть заданы на русском языке.

Comment: Интересно, людей с ником "Иван Александров" не смущает писать по-английски на ruSO? Иван, мы прекрасно понимаем русский язык. Поправьте свой вопрос, либо он будет закрыт.

Comment: Доборого времени суток. Суть в вопросе, а не в языке.

Comment: А у вас у ПК, на котором запущен эмулятор, камера есть?

Comment: Ноутбук с фронтальной камерой, установлена OS Ubuntu, Android Studio + встроенный эммулятор. При тестирование на ноутбуке не переключается на камеру. При тестирование на телефоне открывается камера делается фото но не жмется галочка! (для сохранения на диск). Если выходит ошибка непонятно где смотреть логи.